# Combine the values based on another value in the dataset MYSQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and i've created a dataset on MYSQL 8.0 on DBFiddle and when querying it, i'm trying to combine values into a list based on How many instances they appear in the table which are as follows:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Amy Winehouse | Azure Services |
| Amy Winehouse | VPN Problems |
| Amy Winehouse | Connectivity |
| Freddie Mercury | Equipment |
| Freddie Mercury | Remote Setup |
| Freddie Mercury | Troubleshooting |
| Jimi Hendrix | System Updates |
| Jimi Hendrix | Hardware Repair |
| Jimi Hendrix | Software Install |

Whereas what I want to show is:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Amy Winehouse | Azure Services, VPN Problems, Connectivity |
| Freddie Mercury | Equipment, Remote Setup, Troubleshooting |
| Jimi Hendrix | System Updates, Hardware Repair, Software Install |

I've trawled through answers on Stackoverflow and the general consensus seems to be either using XML or String_Agg to combine them, however neither of these work, String_Agg is not recognised as a command and nothing to do with XML seems to work at all, I'm unsure if it even works on SQL 8.0 on DBfiddle.

Is there another way to achieve this other than through String_agg or XML?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: then look for Group_CONCAT

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find the solution

```
create table test(Heading_1 varchar(100),Heading_2 varchar(100));

insert into test values
('Amy Winehouse',   'Azure Services'),
('Amy Winehouse',   'VPN Problems'),
('Amy Winehouse',   'Connectivity'),
('Freddie Mercury', 'Equipment'),
('Freddie Mercury', 'Remote Setup'),
('Freddie Mercury', 'Troubleshooting'),
('Jimi Hendrix',    'System Updates'),
('Jimi Hendrix',    'Hardware Repair'),
('Jimi Hendrix',    'Software Install');

select Heading_1 as 'Heading 1', GROUP_CONCAT(Heading_2) as 'Heading 2' from test group by Heading_1;
```

Output:

[image]